# Let $x_4,x_3,x_2,x_1$ be the solutions of $2x^4+3x^3-3x^2-3x+2=0$, find $S=|x_1|+|x_2|+|x_3|+|x_4|$

Tags: polynomials, roots

How would one approach finding $S=|x_1|+|x_2|+|x_3|+|x_4|$ if $x_4,x_3,x_2,x_1$ are the solutions of $2x^4+3x^3-3x^2-3x+2=0$?

I tried thinking about Viete's formulas to find the sum of the roots, without the absolute value, but that doesn't seem helpful. I also don't think I need to find each solution because there wouldn't be enough time in the exam I'm preparing for to do this. Would analysis be helpful here? If you have any hints on how to do this, they'd be much appreciated!

Comment: This would be easier if we had $-3x^3$ instead of $3x^3$ cause the polynomial would now be symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial should be factored

$$2 x^4+3 x^3-3 x^2-3 x+2=\left(x^2+x-1\right) \left(2 x^2+x-2\right)=0$$

Then it's easy to get the 4 roots (2 roots for each factor)

$$\left\{x\to \frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{5}-1\right)\right\},\left\{x\to \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)\right\},\left\{x\to \frac{1}{4} \left(-\sqrt{17}-1\right)\right\},\left\{x\to \frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{17}-1\right)\right\}$$

Hence the sum S over the absolut values of the roots is

$$S=| x_1| +| x_2| +| x_3| +| x_4| =\sqrt{5}+\frac{\sqrt{17}}{2}$$